# hapi-swagger Joi string example

Tags: joi, hapi-swagger

I'm having an issue with adding proper examples to hapi-swagger with Joi. When I add .example('') to either the response schema or validate { payload: {} } it's adding an additional obj with a value.

```
    response: {
      schema: Joi.object().keys({
        name: Joi.string().example('Coinbase'),
        baseCurrency: Joi.string()
          .valid('USD', 'EUR', 'MXN', 'ETH', 'LTH', 'BTC'),
      }),
    },
    validate: {
      payload: Joi.object().keys({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        baseCurrency: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    },
```

[image]

What I expect is on the example value to have

{
  "name": "Coinbase",
  "baseCurrency": "USD"
}

Not

{
  "name": {
    "value": "Coinbase"
  },
  "baseCurrency": {
    "value": "USD"
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade joi to v13.
Track issue on hapi-swagger github: https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/issues/540